# Windows Phone 8 External IP vs local hostname

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-phone-8, udp

My intention is to receive UDP messages over the internet on a windows phone 8.

*-> First question: am I wrong assuming that this is possible?*

**Test setup:**

- WIFI switched off, cellular data on
- Running NetworkInformation.GetHostNames() I get one host with IANA network code 344, IP Address was "10.146.8.159".
- Opening icanhazip.com at the same time in the browser I get an IP Address of "192.230.159.176".

*-> Second question: why are these two IP addresses different?*

**My code is:**

```
public async void Start()
{
  m_rxSocket = new DatagramSocket();
  m_rxSocket.MessageReceived += MessageReceived;
  await m_rxSocket.BindServiceNameAsync("57000");
}

private async void MessageReceived(DatagramSocket sender, DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs socketEventData)
{
  // This is never called
}
```

The problem is that the method MessageReceived is never called despite:

- Sending a UDP message to 10.146.8.159 as well as 192.230.159.176 over the internet
- Registering the ID_CAP_NETWORKING

*-> Third question: why is no message received by the setup above?*

(-> Fourth question: anyone else thinking that wp development with silverlight was superior to this new apis that are smelling C++ all over...?)

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have found what was wrong:

Lack of UDP hole punching was the reason for the behaviour and adding UDP hole punching the solution to make it work.